# Expo React Native: expected version range: ~6.0.0 - actual version installed: ^5.0.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

After updating Expo SDK 33 to 34, I started noticing an error about several expo npm packages having to be at least v6.0.0...

```
$ expo start -c
Starting project at /Users/nyxynyx/expoapp
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002

Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - expo-ads-admob - expected version range: ~6.0.0 - actual version installed: ^5.0.1
 - expo-analytics-amplitude - expected version range: ~6.0.0 - actual version installed: ^5.0.1
 - expo-barcode-scanner - expected version range: ~6.0.0 - actual version installed: ^5.0.1
 - expo-permissions - expected version range: ~6.0.0 - actual version installed: ^5.0.1
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]

...
```

Went ahead to update these packages

```
$ npm install --save expo-ads-admob expo-analytics-amplitude expo-barcode-scanner expo-permissions
npm WARN The package react-native-dotenv is included as both a dev and production dependency.

+ expo-permissions@5.0.1
+ expo-ads-admob@5.0.1
+ expo-analytics-amplitude@5.0.1
+ expo-barcode-scanner@5.0.1
updated 4 packages and audited 38421 packages in 5.052s
found 11 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Also tried clearing caches using:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
watchman watch-del-all 
rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro*
expo start -c
```

However, the same warning message about requiring v6.0.0+ exists. The app appears to run ok (Barcode scanner, etc) in the Expo iOS client. What should we do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `Expo`, I don't think it's the right way to install it. If you want to install your own module from `Expo`, use this command.

**Example**

```
expo install expo-ads-admob
```

Comment: Using `expo install` instead of `npm install --save`  successfully installed v6.0.0 version of those expo packages!

Comment: `package.json` has also been automatically updated to reflect `"^6.0.0"` version requirements. If `node_modules` is removed and to be re-installed, is it ok to simply run `npm install`? Or do we have to use `expo install <packagename>` to install the expo packages separately?

Comment: Package in case of removing and installing `node_modules`. `npm install` or `yarn install` should be used because version is reflected in Package.json and other modules need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to run "expo update" on the project folder.